# Error in download.file(url, method = method, ...) : cannot open destfile <xxxxx>, reason 'Permission denied' al intentar descargar datos de un sitio

Tags: r

Tengo un problema con la descarga de un documento zip de [esta página](https://www.latinobarometro.org/latContents.jsp). Quiero acceder a la colección de datos Rrds de 2020. Por ahora he intentado con lo siguiente:

```
    install.packages("downloader")
    library(downloader)
    url <- "https://www.latinobarometro.org/latContents.jsp"
    filename <- basename(url)
    destino <- paste0("/F00011656-Latinobarometro_2020_Esp_R_RDS_v_0",filename)
    download(url,destino)
    dat <- read.csv(destino)
```

pero en la ejecución de
`download(url,destino)`

me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
Error in download.file(url, method = method, ...) : 
cannot open destfile '/F00011656-Latinobarometro_2020_Esp_R_RDS_v_0latContents.jsp', 
reason 'Permission denied
```

Realmente requiero su apoyo con comprender mi error de código.

Comment: Asegúrate de tener los permisos adecuados para escribir en la carpeta de destino.

Comment: En línea con lo que te dice Mauricio, si estas en linux/Mac esto `/F00011656-Latinobarometro_2020_Esp_R_RDS_v_0` significa que estás queriendo salvar el archivo en la carpeta root del equipo, y seguro no tienes permiso de hacerlo (a menos que seas el usuario root). Prueba descargarlo en to carpeta personal `~/F00011656-Latinobarometro_2020_Esp_R_RDS_v_0`